# Using logic as parameter in c++

Tags: c++

Assuming I have a class and vector like below

```
class A {
private:
    int a;
    std::string b;
public:
    A();
    virtual ~A();
}

std::vector<A> vecA;
```

I want find in vecA object (obj) that satisfy logic condition (eg: obj.a < 10). Do you have any idea to create a class for searching. Example `class B`, that i can pass logic requirement easy like:

```
B b;
Vector<A> findA = b.Find<A>(vecA, A::a < 10);
```

class B may don't exactly like above but hope it can meet requirement present logic statement easily. Thank for helping. Sorry because of stupid question.

Comment: @nibot: Yes, I will check now. Thanks.

Comment: You may want to pass a callable object (e.g., function pointer, class or lambda expression) to the find() method. Many methods in <algorithms> are designed to accepte such objects. You can refer to their source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In functional programming this operation -- where we select all those items from some collection that match a particular *predicate function* -- is called *filtering*.  In modern C++, it can be accomplished with [`std::copy_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_if) or `remove_if` from `<algorithms>`, depending on your situation.

Comment: Thanks. I want to pass A::a < 10 as parameter.

Comment: You can do that by passing an *anonymous function*, otherwise known as a *[lambda expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)*. Try `[x]{return x.A < 10;}`.